# Symfony2 routing resource and type

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I followed this [tutorial](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html) and got SonataAdminBundle successfully installed. However, I'm very new to Symfony2 and I'm having trouble understanding parts of the routing configuration found in the tutorial.

```
# app/config/routing.yml    
_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

1. Where does **resource: .** get the routes from?
2. What does type: **sonata_admin** mean?

Thanks!

Comment: please read the symfony 2 book at least you obviously did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` key permits to the different routing loaders to know which one supports loading this routing resource.

The `resource: .` is just here to say that it will load everything. In fact, the [routing loader](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Route/AdminPoolLoader.php#L52) does not care about this parameter, that's why you put `.`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't know about custom routing loaders until now. ;)